# do we need to protect single assignment or if statement for threadsafety

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

Suppose I have like :

```
static int write_log = 0;

void *logger__run(void *arg){
    // logger thread execution.
    while(1){
         // get log message from shared queue.
         if(write_log){
             // just checking write_log value.
             // write logs till write_log is true.
         }
         // destroy log message.
    }
}

void logger__set_logging(int p_write_log){
    // other threads can start / stop logging by logger thread.
    // just assigning value.
    write_log = p_write_log;
}

int logger__is_logging(void){
    // other threads can check whether logger thread is logging or not.
    // just returning value.
    return write_log;
}
```

The function `logger__run()` will be executed by logger thread. Other threads can start / stop logging by logger thread by setting `write_log` shared variable. Other threads can also check if logger is logging or not.

As you can see, there are only single statements like: **assignment** or **returning value** or **checking in while loop**. So, do we need this `write_log` access to be protected with locks?

Comment: So one thread can switch on and off the logging for all other threads? I think you'd be better off having one variable per thread and check that before you add to the log queue.

Comment: One variable per thread? How? Yes, I think it will be better to turn on/off logging, by single thread. But any other thread check whether its logger is logging or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes. `logger__run` may read an incorrect value for `write_log` because the assignment in `logger__set_logging` is not atomic (thus, some bytes of the int value may have been written and others may have yet to come within this single assignment).

Comment: Presumably, making it a `byte` or `char` would get around this?  Also, would you need to mark it `volatile` to ensure the logging thread doesn't cache its value?

Comment: @TripeHound No, and volatile doesn't matter. You need to lock it or make it atomic.

Comment: Would you not _also_ need to make it volatile?  Or does locking/atomic-ing ensure it will never read a stale value?

Comment: @TripeHound I have yet to see where it says that volatile has anything to do with atomicity.

Comment: @2501 I think it originates from the [Visual Studio extension to `volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx)

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan That is a compiler specific keyword. You link even says: *The volatile keyword in C++11 ISO Standard code is to be used only for hardware access; do not use it for inter-thread communication.* _ 
@ brb tea  No.

Comment: @2501 Well the keyword is c++, the behavior is specific to ms, as I stated. Perhaps I should have targeted my reply to TripeHound, as I was trying to explain how `volatile` does not do he what seems to think. In other words, I was trying to support your case.

Comment: It is correct that you need volatile for variables shared with a callback function, but this is _not_ for thread-safety reasons, but to _protect yourself against incorrect compiler optimizations_ where the compiler incorrectly assumes that a value has not been modified, because it cannot predict how/when callback functions are called.

Comment: @Lundin: You'd only need `volatile` in that case if the compiler is horribly broken, in which case you shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That has been the case with many a compiler over the years, particularly specialized compilers for embedded systems. While mainstream PC/desktop compilers tend to handle callbacks well.